# How to call getLooper() on main Thread?

Tags: java, android, android-handler, android-looper

In Android, Main Thread & `HandlerThread` has Looper & MessageQueue by default. I can call getLooper() on handlerThread object, but why not on main Thread ?

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread();
Looper htLooper = ht.getLooper();      // Works fine

Thread mainThread = Looper.getMainLooper().getThread();
Looper mainLooper = mainThread.getLooper();    // getLooper() doesn't compile.
```

In a real scenario, one would never need to use *getLooper()* on mainThread; we can just call `Looper.getMainLooper()`. I would just like to know why it doesn't work.

I understand it from a Java perspective, that `Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()` returns a `java.lang.Thread`, and Thread class doesn't have a *getLooper()* method; but Android's main thread does. Can Main Thread be accessed as a `HandlerThread` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the source code, you will see that the thread inside the looper is not of type `HandlerThread`:

```
60       final Thread mThread;
...
188      mThread = Thread.currentThread();
```

---

> Can Main Thread be accessed as a HandlerThread

No